# Why I am Getting NullPointerException android.content.pm.ProviderInfo after Defining a FileProvider authorities attribute

Tags: android, github, android-8.0-oreo, android-fileprovider, android-8.1-oreo

Will i googled about this and i could not find what i was mssing

i have this library form Github that present Image Intent to chose either form gallery or open camera :

```
'com.github.Mariovc:ImagePicker:latestVersion' 1.2.2
```

i added provider in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

and  here is the  xml/provider_paths:

```
<paths>
<external-path path="." name="external_files" />
```

when i ran the application on galaxy j.7 Android Api 5.1.1  i get this error :

```
    Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/co.my_city.development/cache
04-05 13:31:32.171 28647-28647/co.my_city.development W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
04-05 13:31:32.171 28647-28647/co.my_city.development W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:584)
04-05 13:31:32.171 28647-28647/co.my_city.development W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:558)
04-05 13:31:32.171 28647-28647/co.my_city.development W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
04-05 13:31:32.171 28647-28647/co.my_city.development W/System.err:     at com.mvc.imagepicker.ImagePicker.getPickImageIntent(ImagePicker.java:219)
04-05 13:31:32.171 28647-28647/co.my_city.development W/System.err:     at com.mvc.imagepicker.ImagePicker.startChooser(ImagePicker.java:184)
04-05 13:31:32.171 28647-28647/co.my_city.development W/System.err:     at com.mvc.imagepicker.ImagePicker.pickImage(ImagePicker.java:165)
```

but on nexues Emulater Api  i get this errro :

```
 va.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
04-05 06:35:23.650 3835-3835/co.my_city.development W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:584)
04-05 06:35:23.650 3835-3835/co.my_city.development W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:558)
04-05 06:35:23.650 3835-3835/co.my_city.development W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
04-05 06:35:23.650 3835-3835/co.my_city.development W/System.err:     at com.mvc.imagepicker.ImagePicker.getPickImageIntent(ImagePicker.java:219)
04-05 06:35:23.650 3835-3835/co.my_city.development W/System.err:     at com.mvc.imagepicker.ImagePicker.startChooser(ImagePicker.java:184)
```

what is it that i missing here ?

Comment: Do you have the `<provider>` in the right spot in the manifest? It belongs inside the `<application>` tags, but not inside anything else, like an `<activity>` or `<service>`.

Comment: @MikeM. yes it is in <application> tag

Comment: Then it would seem that you're passing the wrong authority in a `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same and after debugging i got that in FileProvide.class, on following point

```html
private final String mAuthority;

SimplePathStrategy(String authority) 
{
  this.mAuthority = authority;
}
```

it throw exception, as this.mAuthority is not initialised properly. File on this stage is locked and can not be modified.
(Sorry I had to point out this issue in comments but due to less reputation points I am highlighting here in answer section).